# Pythagoras theorem proof for n-dimensions using the L2-norm

Tags: solution-verification, induction, normed-spaces

> The Pythagoras theorem asserts for a set of $n$ orthogonal vectors $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ for $i = 1,\dots, n$ that
> $$ {\Bigg \lvert\Bigg \lvert \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \Bigg \lvert \Bigg \lvert_{2}^{2}} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert \lvert x_{i} \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2}.\tag{1}$$
> Establish the result for general $n$ by induction.

**For  $n=1$**:

This case is trivial since in both sides of $(1)$ the sum vanishes to $1$ such that the equality is held.

**For $(n-1) \implies n$** :

\begin{align}
\Bigg \lvert\Bigg \lvert \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_{i} \Bigg \lvert \Bigg \lvert_{2}^{2} &= \lvert \lvert x_{1} + x_{2} + \dots + x_{n-1} \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \lvert \lvert  x_{i} \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2}  + \underbrace{\sum_{i \neq j} x_{i} x_{j}}_{=0 \ \text{since }\ x_{i} \perp x_{j}} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \lvert \lvert  x_{i} \rvert \rvert_{2}^{2} 
\end{align}

I'm not sure if this proof holds and/or if some steps are missing. Could anyone perhaps confirm ?

Comment: Your result does not use induction.

Comment: Your proof is fine, though you're proving it directly and not by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is good, but it does not rely on induction. Here is the Inductive Step.

Assume the theorem holds for $n-1$ vectors, and let $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be orthogonal. Then note that $x_1 + \ldots + x_{n-1} = y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is orthogonal to $x_n$. Thus,
$$
\begin{split}
\|x_1+\ldots x_{n-1}+x_n\|_2^2
 &= \|y+x_n\|_2^2 \quad \text{apply theorem for 2 vectors} \\ 
 &= \|y\|_2^2 + \|x_n\|^2 \\
 &= \|x_1+\ldots x_{n-1}\|_2^2 + \|x_n\|^2 \quad \text{apply theorem for $n-1$ vectors}\\
 &= \|x_1\|_2^2 + \ldots + \|x_{n-1}\|_2^2 + \|x_n\|^2
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: @hitechphysics you are welcome, glad to be of help